# Not able to redirect to NotFoundComponent in the right way?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm having some issues routing the notfound page. I'm using Angular (typescript). In my app I have 4 main Routing:
App-Routing, Login-Routing, User-Routing and Admin-Routing.
I created the NotFoundComponent, and if I add this syntax:

```
{ path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent},
{ path: '**', redirectTo:'/404'}
```

If I add it to the UserRouting, when I login as admin it goes to 404;
If I add it to the AdminRouting, when I login as user it goes to 404;
If I add it to the AppRouting, when I login as both user and admin it goes to 404;
What should I do to make things work?
Here are my routing codes:

UserRouting:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'user-dashboard', component: UserLayoutComponent, 
  canActivate:[AuthGuard],
  children:[
    { path: '', component: UserDashboardComponent},
    { path: 'profilo-user', component: ProfilouserComponent},
    { path: 'preferiti', component: CarrelloComponent},
    { path: 'contatti', component: ContattiComponent},
    { path: 'prodotti-negozio'/*/:id:nome*/, component: ProdottiNegozioComponent}
  ]},
];
```

AdminRouting:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin-dashboard', component: AdminLayoutComponent, 
  canActivate:[AuthGuard], canActivateChild:[AuthGuard], children:[
    { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent},
    { path: 'profilo-admin', component: ProfiloadminComponent},
    { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent},
    { path: 'work-in-progress', component: WorkInProgressComponent}
  ]},
];
```

AppRouting:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo:'/404'}
];
```

LoginRouting:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

What should I do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

How your routes are connected? Maybe you should list them in one place to simplify your routing logic?
For example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  ...authRoutes,
  ...usersRoutes,
  ...adminsRoutes,
  { path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo:'/404'}
];
```

Comment: I tried to put AdminRoute inside the AppRouting, but the issue was that logging in with admin, didn't load me the navbar, which is in a folder in Layout

Comment: Did you check your <router-outlet>? Is it in correct place?

Comment: router-outlet is in the app-component.html

Comment: and navbar is in app-component also? or somewhere deeper? when navbar is not loaded then looks like it is in child route component not in app?